# Do reactions like Opportunity Attacks use the regular Attack Roll?

Tags: dnd-5e, opportunity-attack, reactions

From my past question, I understand that each attack requires an attack roll 1d20+mod, but does this extend to reactions such as Attack of Opportunity as well?

The PHB didn't seem to say anything about this.

Answer (score 15):

Page 195 of the *Player's Handbook* says:

> To make [an] opportunity attack, you use your reaction to make one melee attack against the provoking creature.

Thus when you make an opportunity attack, you are making a regular melee attack and use all the normal rules for making one; the fact that it is being made as a reaction is not relevant.